# Complexity of searching a key in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of this code:

```
 if 'key' in my_dict:
    print(my_dict['key'])
```

I just want to make sure the condition takes O(1). Is it right?

Comment: That's correct (on average) -- See [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: Are you including the time it takes for people to remind you not to call your dictionaries `dict`?  Because I think that's formally unbounded, even though average case is O(1)..

Comment: I think you meant `print(dict['key'])`.  Also, as @DSM said, _never_ name a variable after a built-in.  If you must use a name that is taken, at least place an underscore after it: `dict_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#dict):

```
Operation Average Case Amortized Worst Case

Get Item  O(1)         O(n)

x in s    O(1)         O(n)  #From sets
```